# If/else problems in python

Tags: python, if-statement

Ok, I'm gonna explain this as best I can.

I am trying to make an if/else statement in python that basically informs the user if they put in the right age based on raw input, but I keep getting an error in terms of my if statement. Can I get some help?

```
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()

print '%s/%s/%s %s:%s:%s' % (now.month, now.day, now.year, now.hour,now.minute, now.second)
print "Welcome to the beginning of a Awesome Program created by yours truly."
print " It's time for me to get to know a little bit about you"

name = raw_input("What is your name?")
age = raw_input("How old are you?")

        if age == 1 and <= 100
            print "Ah, so your name is %s, and you're %s years old. " % (name, age)
                else:
                        print " Yeah right!"
```

Comment: You're misinterpreting how conditions work. You can't chain dependencies after a variable; although that would certainly be nice in some situations.

Comment: The condition doesn't make much sense either if you think about it. Your seeing if the age is exactly equal to one, then trying to check if it's less than or equal to 100 (unless I'm misinterpreting the intent). If something is equal to 1, it will also always be less than 100; so the second condition is redundant.

Comment: `if 1 <= age <= 100:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the formatted and corrected code:

```
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()
print '%s/%s/%s %s:%s:%s' % (now.month, now.day, now.year, now.hour,now.minute, now.second)
print "Welcome to the beginning of a Awesome Program created by yours truly."
print " It's time for me to get to know a little bit about you"

name = raw_input("What is your name?")
age = raw_input("How old are you?")

while int(age) < 1 or int(age) > 100:
    print " Yeah right!"
    age = raw_input("How old are you?")

print "Ah, so your name is %s, and you're %s years old. " % (name, age)
```

Also, double check indents and your logic for the age.

Comment: So should i write to make my program retype the age after the else statement? I want to make it like a loop until the task has been completed.

Answer (score 2):

change your if statement to this:

`if age >=1 and age <=100:`

two things:

1. `if age >=1 and <=100` is missing `age <=100`
2. you are missing a `:` at the end

Comment: I don't understand your quesiton, what do you mean by "retype the age after the else statement" ?

if u want to make it a loop just put all of this inside a for i in range(10):
where 10 is the number of iterations.